# Filter an array with typegaurd doesn't produce an array of that type

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I'm having trouble filtering an array that's of a union type into a single type.

I've got code very similar to this example:

```typescript
interface Section {
  type: 'section';
  name: string;
  children: (Section | Link)[];
}

interface Link {
  type: 'link';
  title: string;
  children: []
}

const json = JSON.stringify({
  type: 'section',
  name: 'Parent',
  children: [
    { type: 'section', name: 's1', children: [] },
    { type: 'section', name: 's2', children: [{ type: 'section', name: 's2', children: [] }] },
    { type: 'link', title: 'l1', children: [] },
    { type: 'section', name: 's3', children: [] },
    { type: 'link', title: 'l2', children: [] },
  ]
});

let parentSection: Section | Link = JSON.parse(json);

const sections = parentSection.children.filter((item): item is Section => !!item && item.type === 'section');
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQWYB7EyDeAsAFDLJgCeADhAFzIDkAzhlrgwNwlkhwC2dZEzBRQAcy6lkCABbAANgBMoEEPQAU6TDjwAfZABlQAawCUAbQC6kgL4kSoSLEQojIYwW7lqghvJOcXlhg8oLCoiASXrIKyqr0ViR2xCQIuMLIAFZMuMgAvMgAUqgA8gByAHTh4sAwFOpEUpQ09MysOgwANF68Aq0ACnAq4F3RckrDCV5k+N4tjCza7J3Ivb5MAIxd0uNxashWyDbdUjNz6+3Lq-zrAEzbMRPxB7PNF0sg22utTPcrj3sEpYjsDjtMCOdWv53NtgqEoVt-rtJgdQScyGc3j9Lp8Vt8FgBmB7I56HMGnCFYxjQ4yw4AhXzyP47WIosno5CWJKmSQkUJgZBUIaqMBaNj7MU6ZD6NweArFcoVIVQFjqbK4Hn2YhpEAZRbipj5QXC8CS3AVAHDCowBROdTqekQPimeiOvjIYCGs14PIAPmQAEIA27kAAyUMeyB8CpvfJ5AptD4MTXEIA)

`JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are there so TS doesn't infer the type of `parentSection` from the data, which comes from an API in real world.

The problem is that the type of `sections` as inferred by TS is `(Section | Link)[]`, but I'd expect it to be `Section[]` or `Section[] | []`.

What do I need to change here to make this work as I expect/want it to work? I can't affect the data itself, but I am the one writing types for it, so I change play with those. The `Link` items always come with the `children` array without any items in it.

I'd really appreciate some help. Thank you!

Comment: `const sections = parentSection.children.filter((item): item is Section => !!item && item.type === 'section') as Section[];` can't you write it like this? I

Comment: I could, but if anything then changes with the types for this, I'd like it to alert me of potential problems. Casting would hide that error.

Comment: This is a known issue, `filter()` doesn't do the right thing with unions of array types. [ms/TS#44373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373) seems to be the currently open issue about this.  Generally if an array like `A[] | B[]` is not behaving the way you want, I'd (safely) widen to `readonly (A | B)[]` and then call `filter()` on that,  [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mqQ4Rm).  This should be relatively type safe (changes to types should cause errors).  If you want me to write this up as an answer, let me know.  Otherwise, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: With the help of your comment I actually got an idea to do `parentSection.children.map((i) => i).filter((item): item is Section => !!item && item.type === 'section');` This fixes the type that goes into the filter. It's a redundant `map`, but it's used in a low count arrays so it's not that problematic. With your solution, I'd be interested to know it there's an inline way of doing it instead of using an interim variable (`ps`).

Comment: So do you want me to write up an answer or look for an alternative solution instead?  The interim variable is type safe in a way that an inline version involving `parentSection.children as readonly (Section | Link)[]` would be.

Comment: Both your way and mine are a kind of workarounds, but might be useful for people that get tripped up by it right now and want a way around it. So, yes, please do write up a solution. If you could add that this is a result of bug and something that's being worked on with links to GitHub issues, it would be great. Once the fix or a proper solution comes out, we can edit the answer.

Comment: It's more of a design limitation than a bug; it's not that the compiler is doing something *incorrect* here, it's more like it is not performing enough analysis to realize what you're trying to do.  Synthesizing call signatures for unions of functions is a higher-order type operation that is probably intractable in the general case (e.g., one or both functions are overloaded and/or generic).  I will write something up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that you have a value of [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type `(Section | Link)[] | []` and you're trying to call its `filter()` method, which is therefore also a union of function types.  Taking a union of functions with differing call signatures and deciding which calls are safe is not a trivial task.  Conceptually a union of call signatures should take an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the parameters (due to [contravariance of function/method parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_parameter_type)), but there are a lot of practical issues that make it harder.

Originally, TypeScript just gave up and didn't let you call such functions at all. See [microsoft/TypeScript#7294](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294).  Then TypeScript 3.3 [introduced support for calling some union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) via a fix in [microsoft/TypeScript#29011](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011), which would synthesize a single call signature using the intersections of the parameters from the individual union members' call signatures, as long as no more than one member's call signature is [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) and no more than one member's call signature is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  This improved things a lot, but in particular array methods tend to be generic and/or overloaded so unions of arrays still had few useful methods available.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#36390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36390).  A little more work has been done in [microsoft/TypeScript#31023](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31023) to allow some generic methods to be called in unions, and as of now, only `reduce()` is completely uncallable for unions of functions.  Still, it's not perfect, and
[microsoft/TypeScript#44373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373) is the currently open issue about this.  Your `filter()` call is specifically trying to use the overloads where the callback is a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), and that's just not supported at this time.

---

So for now there are only workarounds.  My go-to workaround:

Generally speaking when you have an array of type `Array<A> | Array<B>` and you're only going to be reading from it, it should be safe to treat it as a value of type `ReadonlyArray<A | B>`.  In fact, the compiler will generally let you perform this widening:

```
parentSection.children; //  (Section | Link)[] | []
const pc: readonly (Section | Link)[] = parentSection.children; // no error
```

Note that the element type for `[]` is [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), so `ReadonlyArray<A | B>` in this case would be `ReadonlyArray<(Section | Link) | never>` which is just `ReadonlyArray<Section | Link>`.

Once you have a `ReadonlyArray<A | B>`, it's no longer a union type (its elements are union typed but not the array itself) and you can call `filter()` with impunity:

```
const sections = pc.filter((item): item is Section => !!item && item.type === 'section');
// const sections: Section[]
```

Note that you could shorten this to a one-liner:

```
const sections = (parentSection.children as readonly (Section | Link)[]).
  filter((item): item is Section => !!item && item.type === 'section');
// const sections: Section[]
```

but that's a bit less type safe since [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) allow (unsafe) narrowing/downcasting as well as (safe) widening/upcasting, whereas [type annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) on variables only allows widening/upcasting.

---

There are, of course, other viable workarounds (e.g., you mentioned using `map(x => x)`, which works because of some of the above PRs, and then it becomes a single array type).  Until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#44373 is addressed, you'll have to stick with your favorite workaround.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQWYB7EyDeAsAFDLJgCeADhAFzIDkAzhlrgwNwlkhwC2dZEzBRQAcy6lkCABbAANgBMoEEPQAU6TDjwAfZABlQAawCUAbQC6kgL4kSoSLEQojIYwW7lqghvJOcXlhg8oLCoiASXrIKyqr0ViR2xCQIuMLIAFZMuMgAvMgAUqgA8gByAHTh4sAwFOpEUpQ09MysOgwANF68Aq0ACnAq4F3RckrDCV5k+N4tjCza7J3Ivb5MAIxd0uNxashWyDbdUjNz6+3Lq-zrAEzbMRPxB7PNF0sg22utTPcrj3sEpYjsDjtMCOdWv53NtgqEoVt-rtJgdQScyGc3j9Lp8Vt8FgBmB7I56HMGnCFYxjQ4yw4AhXzyP47WIosno5CWJKmSQkUJgZBUIaqMBaNj7MU6ZD6NweArFcoVIVQFjqbK4Hn2YjKkWS3AVAHDDjIAD0JrImhx0sMJgswP0iWIaRAGSoCHoKjgilw8goyEtH2tsrt+UFwvAepABpJIGNZtW2GQ0Cg2CgWudGUW4qYobdFRgCic6nU9IgfFM9FLfGQwBzkfyAD5kABCZtV5AAMg7NcgfAqb3yeQKbQ+DE1xHjGYFWZ0THokcd6fS05xv1D6h1EZx0dZqmQcBznu9IF9-vrMttVlMFS8BfkRZLvYrPbLNbrVryTdb7a7L77A6HYcZ3YcdJ2XIRV1ueccUXFI4KAA)