# Why do I have to filter twice for my type guard to be effective?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For some reason, I have to filter my array twice with the same type guard to get my expected result:

```
// typing of arr as received from another function
const arr = [] as string[] | (string | false)[]

// my type guard
const truish = <T>(x: T | false): x is T => x !== false

// unexpected: (string | false)[]
const unexpected = arr.filter(truish)

// expected: string[]
const expected = arr.filter(truish).filter(truish)
```

Could someone explain why I need to filter twice, and how I might rework my type guard (or otherwise) so that I can filter once?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70745701/filter-an-array-with-typegaurd-doesnt-produce-an-array-of-that-type.

Comment: @Blackhole Thank you, I think that pretty much answers it. The tl;dr seems to be that narrowing unions of arrays can be expensive, therefore TS punts. It's effectively a bug with workarounds. I'll close this in favor of the referenced question.

Comment: Yeah, this is the same issue as the other question.  TS doesn't support calling unions of generic overloads, which is what you're doing.  One workaround would be to widen to a `readonly` array-of-unions instead of a union-of-arrays, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG4kkw).